# Enabling clipboard history in windows 10

Tags: windows, clipboard

This question and my answer were originally posted on the Stack Exchange site, but when I asked the moderators to move it here, they closed it instead, so I've moved it myself as I believe my question and subsequent research and answer are of interest to those with a similar problem

I am running Windows 10 Home with the latest updates.

I have done the following.

Tried to change the clipboard history enabled in settings, but it's switched off and greyed out and the message "some of these settings are managed by your organization" is displayed.

Since this is the Home Edition it does not come with group policy editor installed (gpedit.msc) so I had to download and install it.

There are several videos on Youtube showing ways of removing the message and allowing changes. None of them work.

I do finally find "Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > OS Policies > Allow clipboard History" and enable it. But still no clipboard history, although Settings now shows it is supposed to be enabled, albeit greyed out and the message is still there. And Clipboard History (Win-V) still doesn't work.

Any ideas how to remove the annoying message and get clipboard history working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found a partial solution using Regedit. Go to

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Clipboard
```

and change

```
EnableClipboardHistory
```

to 1.

This, on it's own, still does not work, but going to

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\System\
```

and changing

```
AllowClipboardHistory
```

to 1 finally enables Win-V and in Clipboard Settings the switch is no longer greyed out and can be operated.

The "some of these settings are managed by your organization" is still displayed, but enough for today, I've achieved 80% of what I wanted.

**Much later**
I finally found a Google article about Chrome browser being "managed by your organisation" when it is on your own private PC. It gives several different versions of instructions on how to remove this setting. It can be found [here](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/9844476)

**Caveats**
It talks about having a Google administrators account for one method. Not a lot of use for a single home PC. Your ordinary google login won't work.

In the Windows method there are a scary number of Registry entries to remove. Most delete OK, but one or two refuse to be deleted or don't exist. There is also a file to delete, but for me, that didn't exist either. However I deleted as many as I could and Chrome doesn't appear to be "managed" any more after a restart. Early days.

**2 years later**

About 6 months after taking back control of Chrome, I noticed that it had reverted to "managed by your organisation" again. Why I don't know, possibly due to either a Windows update or a Chrome one. Nevertheless I've no real need to change anything currently restricted so I haven't gone through the exercise again. Maybe I will look into generating a script to perform all the alterations automatically if I need it. If so I will post a link here.