# Why does clipboard history instantly turn itself off/refuse to turn on? Windows 11 Home Edition

Tags: windows, windows-11, copy-paste, clipboard, history

I have Windows 11 Home Edition, and pressing WIN+V opens up the "clipboard history" box. It says "Let's get started / Turn on clipboard history to copy and view multiple items." When I click "Turn on," the message disappears for a fraction of a second then reappears. It won't turn on, or rather it looks like it's trying to turn on then immediately giving up. There is no error message or other indication of something going wrong.

I've tried:

- enabling clipboard history from the Settings
- installing group policy editor to enable clipboard history in admin settings
- editing registry to enable clipboard history for my user and for all users

All to no effect. I also have not been able to find another example of someone else having exactly the same problem. See [Enabling clipboard history in windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1721424/enabling-clipboard-history-in-windows-10) for example: my problem is not the same and the solution there didn't work for me.

How can I enable and use the clipboard history?

Comment: Try to test Windows integrity by running the commands [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and then [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: If DISM and SFC do not solve the problem for you, you may need to consider a Windows 11 Repair Install from the Microsoft Media Creation Link.

Comment: 1. Note that there is a Group Policy setting to disable Clipboard History: https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/110039-enable-disable-clipboard-history-windows-10-a.html 2. If it's not worth the trouble of reinstalling Windows 11, consider a third-party clipboard tool, such as CopyQ, or alternatives: https://alternativeto.net/software/copyq/